# Displaying an icon while JavaScript is still executing code

Tags: javascript, foreach, xmlhttprequest

I have some JavaScript that fetches data from a URL, then loops over the results with a `forEach` loop.

The operation can take up to a minute to complete and so I want to display a loading symbol on the page to indicate to the user that they shouldn't interact with the page yet.

```
function getFloodAreaPolygon() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = floodAreaData[0].polygon;
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            data.features.forEach(geojsonFeature => {
                loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}
```

I wrote some code in `displayLoadingIcon()` to show the icon and `hideLoadingIcon()` to hide it.

I thought that if I displayed the icon at the beginning of the function and hide it after the `request.send(null)` call then it would have endured for the length of the function, however the icon disappears almost instantly.

How can I get around this?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, it's not the AJAX request which is taking up to a minute to complete, it's the processing contained in the `forEach` loop where `loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature)` converts the results to a Leaflet marker object.

Comment: You of course need to hide it after the async request is succeeded (`if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) { *here*`) or possibly after the last `loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature);`

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. `request.send()` doesn't wait for the response, so you're removing the icon before the response is received.

Comment: I need to wait for the code in `loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature)` to finish executing as well though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming loadFloodAreaPolygon is NOT async too, you can do

```js
function getFloodAreaPolygon() {
  displayLoadingIcon(); // here 
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = floodAreaData[0].polygon;
  request.open("GET", url, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      data.features.forEach(geojsonFeature => {
        loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature);
      });
      hideLoadingIcon(); // here
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
  request.send(null);
}
```

If it IS async, then you can do

```
      data.features.forEach((geojsonFeature,i) => {
        loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature);
        if (i === data.features.length-1) hideLoadingIcon();
      });
```

or pass the test into the function:

```
      data.features.forEach((geojsonFeature,i) => {
        loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature,i === data.features.length-1);
      });
```

and move hideLoadingIcon() to the success of loadFloodAreaPolygon

Comment: If the request is synchronous I think the loading icon doesn't appear, because the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: @IvánPérez but it isn't. The default is async=true and OP specified async=true

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the functions like this.

```
count = 0;
function getFloodAreaPolygon() {
    displayLoadingIcon();
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = floodAreaData[0].polygon;
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            data.features.forEach(geojsonFeature => {
            loadFloodAreaPolygon(geojsonFeature);
            if (count == data.features.length-1) hideLoadingIcon();
            count++;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error");
            hideLoadingIcon();
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Won't that hide the icon after the first feature has been processed though? I need to wait for all of them to be processed

Comment: Yes it will try to hide in each iteration

Comment: Modified the post